# Playframework, binary pdf file attachment issue

Tags: email, playframework

I´ve got a pdf file as ByteArray and I want to know if there´s a way to attach it without creating the main file on the server.

The code provided by the Play documentation only allows real files to be attached.

```
EmailAttachment attachment = new EmailAttachment();
attachment.setDescription("A pdf document");
attachment.setPath(Play.getFile("rules.pdf").getPath());
```

I´m using the Playframework Mail module.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Play 1.x uses the [Apache Commons Email](http://commons.apache.org/email/userguide.html) library under the hood, you could use the [MultiPartEmail#attach(DataSource ds, String name, String description)](http://commons.apache.org/email/apidocs/org/apache/commons/mail/MultiPartEmail.html#attach%28javax.activation.DataSource,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method:

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.*;

// create the mail
MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
email.setHostName("mail.myserver.com");
email.addTo("jdoe@somewhere.org", "John Doe");
email.setFrom("me@apache.org", "Me");
email.setSubject("The picture");
email.setMsg("Here is the picture you wanted");

// get your inputstream from your db
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(MyUtils.getBlob());  
DataSource source = new ByteArrayDataSource(is, "application/pdf");  

// add the attachment
email.attach(source, "somefile.pdf", "Description of some file");

// send the email
email.send();
```

Comment: Solved it the way you said. Thanks a lot @nico_ekito

Answer (score 1):

Upcoming Play Version 1.3 will introduce a method `attachDataSource()`, which can be called from within a `Mailer` class. This will allow you to attach a ByteArray as an attachment to emails easily without the need to save them to the disk first or without the need to use the Apache Commons Emails. You can then use the "standard" Play way.

Here is the corresponding feature request in the play bugtracker:
http://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/57987/tickets/1500-adding-maillerattachdatasource-functionality